# Firefox doesn't load jquery from ajax.googleapis.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, firefox

I have Firefox 20.0.1, and the following code that I use in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>-->
```

When I run my page on chrome, opera, safari and IE, everything works perfect, but when I try to run it on Firefox console throws me this error:

```
[13:14:27.848] ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

And when I uncomment the second line for load it localy it works perfectly.

I also tried with `http://` instead of `//` with no luck. It's weird, jQuery is also the first script that my page has to load. Any suggestion?

Comment: See request in network tab. Any error?

Comment: I've got this error: [13:34:27.572] CSP WARN: default-src directive http://alex:80 violated by  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: now I know what is going on, I have to allow the google's domain in the access control header of my htaccess..

Comment: i'd suggest you to post it as answer. This could help futur readers

Comment: @A.Wolff I will, when I confirm it :)

Answer (score 4):

Fixed, the issue was the next:

In my htaccess file I had a X-Content-Security-Policy restriction that didn't specified that the server could load external content from ajax.googleapis.com, so the line was:

```
Header set X-Content-Security-Policy "allow 'self';"
```

So in order to make it work I had to replace it with:

```
Header set X-Content-Security-Policy "allow 'self'; script-src 'self' ajax.googleapis.com;"
```

And case closed! =) Special thank's to A. Wolff for the suggestion..

Comment: I would suggest you to choose it as the best answer because it is the only one and it already solved your problem.